# Python: Stop lists from splitting two-digit numbers apart on input

Tags: python, string, list, int

Whenever my algorithm inputs a two digit number into my list such as 10, it inputs it as `a = [1, 0]`and not `a = [10]` How can I stop this?

My program is meant to take the user's number and generate x amount of generations of the Fibonacci sequence. (1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8...)

Heres my code:

```
def get_integar(help_text):
    global num
    num = int(input(help_text))
a = []
get_integar("Enter number of generations: ")
j = 0
x = 0
sum_jx = 0
for i in range(num):
    if j == 0 and x == 0:
        j = 1
        a.extend(str(j))
        x = 1
        a.extend(str(x))
    else:
        sum_jx = j + x
        a.extend(str(sum_jx))
        x = j
        j = sum_jx
    i = i + 1
print(a)
```

for example here is one outcome with 7 generations:

> Enter number of generations: 7
>   ['1', '1', '2', '3', '5', '8', '1',
>   '3', '2', '1']

it should be

> ['1', '1', '2', '3', '5', '8', '13', '21']

Comment: First of all, if you entered `10`, `num` will be `10`  not `[1,0]` as you said. Second of all, your algorithm of Fibonacci is wrong... check [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/fibonacci-sequence) out.

Comment: Did not get what you are actually asking for

Comment: Ive tested the algoritim it works, the only problem is when the algorithim places a two-digit number (for example 10) in my list it puts it in like ' a = [1, 0 ]' and it should be 'a = [10]'

Answer (score 1):

Try using append instead. Extend will see your string as a iterable. A string as a iterable is just the list of its characters. Also, the first two numbers should be 0 and 1, not 1 and 1 and there is a typo in the name of the function.

```
def get_integar(help_text):
    global num
    num = int(input(help_text))
a = []
get_integar("Enter number of generations: ")
j = 0
x = 0
sum_jx = 0
for i in range(num):
    if j == 0 and x == 0:
        j = 1
        a.append(str(j))
        x = 1
        a.append(str(x))
    else:
        sum_jx = j + x
        a.append(str(sum_jx))
        x = j
        j = sum_jx
    i = i + 1
print(a)
```

Documentation for extend and append from https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html:

**list.append(x)** - *Add an item to the end of the list. Equivalent to a[len(a):] = [x].*
**list.extend(iterable)** - *Extend the list by appending all the items from the iterable. Equivalent to a[len(a):] = iterable.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.extend()` but in another way, simply replace `a.extend(str(x))` to `a.extend([str(x)])` (extends works like arr1+arr2).
See examples here: [What is the difference between Python's list methods append and extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend).

```
def get_integar(help_text):
    global num
    num = int(input(help_text))
a = []
get_integar("Enter number of generations: ")
j = 0
x = 0
sum_jx = 0
for i in range(num):
    if j == 0 and x == 0:
        j = 1
        a.extend([str(j)])
        x = 1
        a.extend([str(x)])
    else:
        sum_jx = j + x
        a.extend([str(sum_jx)])
        x = j
        j = sum_jx
    i = i + 1
print(a)
```

---

EDIT: more nature way is to use `.append(elem)` and then `map(str, arr1)`.